# Creating a single instance of a sound fx in MonoTouch and why is audio so bad for performance?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, mono, xamarin.ios

What I'd like to do is create a re-usable audio class which doesn't allocate/deallocate resources beyond ints initialization/destruction.

So a class such as:

```
class SoundInst
{
   public SoundInst(string sounddir);
   public bool IsPlaying;
   public void Play(float volume);
   public void Stop();
}
```

The reason I ask for such a thing is that I'm finding creating audio on the run is a prohibitively slow affair. My game runs at a solid 60fps without audio but with audio it drops to below 15fps when even one or two sounds are created and played in the same frame.

What I found is that it's not the sounds themselves which are slowing things down but rather  creating them. I can run many sounds simultaneously and keep them on loop and it has no impact on performance.

Any ideas on solving this problem of mine?

Comment: I am not using MonoTouch but is there some thing like `prepareToPlay`  can be used to preload your sound file when your game is loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about mono touch but if you are just using audio in a game i would look at the av foundation framework and more specifically the avaudioplayer.  This is what i use for my games.  It will allow you to load your music asynchronously which should help to fix your performance drop issues.

A link to the framework: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008072

Comment: Unfortunately no you cannot.  If you are trying to make one audio engine to work on many different platforms this will not port between anything not cocoa.